# React useState not updating with data fetched from Firestore"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, next.js13

I'm having a problem with my React component's state not updating with data fetched from Firestore. I've tried various methods to fetch the data and update the state, but none of them seem to work. Below is the code for my GameStats component and the fetchData function:

```
// GameStats component code
import "../../style/game.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import fetchData from "@/service/client";

export const GameStats = ({ elapsedTime }) => {
  const [timeline, setTimeLine] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((data) => setTimeLine(data));
  }, []);

  // ...rest of the component code
};
```

```
// fetchData function code
import { collection, query, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { database } from "./FirebaseService";

export default async function fetchData() {
  const q = query(collection(database, "games"));

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const results = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

    let id = doc.id;
    const data = doc.data();

    results.push({
      id,
      ...data,
    });
  });

  return results;
}
```

I've checked that the data is being fetched from Firestore correctly, as I can see the correct output in the console when I log the results. However, the timeline state remains empty (i.e., []) even after the data is fetched and I attempt to update the state using setTimeLine(data).

What could be the issue, and how can I fix it to ensure that the timeline state is updated with the fetched data?

I've created an array called results in my fetchData function. For each document retrieved from Firestore, I push an object containing the document's data into the results array. After iterating over all the documents, I return the results array.

Comment: Your code is currently missing a catch handler for the `fetchData` promise. You should add this and then reload the page to ensure that the problem is not caused by some timing-based error like accessing the DB before authentication resolves.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I have already resolved the issue, and it wasn't related to the missing catch handler. I made the following changes to the fetchData function to fix the problem:

Instead of using a forEach loop:
`querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { ... })`

I now use the map() method directly on querySnapshot.docs:
`return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => { ... });`

This resolved the issue for me.